# multiple form save in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I would like to code a quiz using multiple pages for form, the values name, email, stadt and land cannot be saved in the database but the form should save all values.

This is the first page of the form:
  page1.php

```
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Personendaten</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="Name" accesskey="U">Name</label>
        <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Namen eingeben" required />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="E-Mail" accesskey="E">E-Mail</label>
        <input name="E-Mail" type="text" id="E-Mail" placeholder="E-Mail" required />        </div>

    <label for="Stadt">Stadt</label>
    <input name="Stadt" type="text" id="Stadt" placeholder="test2" required />

    <div>
        <label for="Land">Land</label>
        <input name="Land" type="text" id="Land" placeholder="test" required />
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>


<input type="submit" name="submit" />


</form>
```

second page of the form
page2.php

```
   <?php
   $name = $_POST['Name'];
   $email = $_POST["E-Mail"];
   $stadt = $_POST["Stadt"];
   $land = $_POST["Land"];
   ?>
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="page3.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?php  $name;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="E-Mail" value="<?php  $email;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Stadt" value="<?php $stadt;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Land" value="<?php $land;?>" />



<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="a1" required > radiobutton1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="a2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="a3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="a4"> a4<br>



<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="b1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="b2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="b3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="b4"> a4<br>



<input type="radio" name="rb3" value="c1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb3" value="c2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb3" value="c3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb3" value="c4"> a4<br>



<input type="radio" name="rb4" value="d1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb4" value="d2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb4" value="d3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb4" value="d4"> a4<br>




<input type="radio" name="rb5" value="d1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb5" value="d2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb5" value="d3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb5" value="d4"> a4<br>



<input type="radio" name="rb6" value="e1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb6" value="e2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb6" value="e3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb6" value="e4"> a4<br>



<input type="radio" name="rb7" value="f1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb7" value="f2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb7" value="f3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb7" value="f4"> a4<br>


<input type="radio" name="rb8" value="g1" required > a1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb8" value="g2"> a2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb8" value="g3" required > a3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb8" value="g4"> a4<br>



<br> <br>







    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

form handler page
page3.php

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{


$name = $_POST["Name"];
$email = $_POST["E-Mail"];
$stadt = $_POST["Stadt"];
$land = $_POST["Land"];
$rb1 = $_POST["rb1"];
$rb2 = $_POST["rb2"];
$rb3 = $_POST["rb3"];
$rb4 = $_POST["rb4"];
$rb5 = $_POST["rb5"];
$rb6 = $_POST["rb6"];
$rb7 = $_POST["rb7"];
$rb8 = $_POST["rb8"];




echo "Successfully submitted\n";

echo("\n");

$score = 0;

if($rb1 == "a1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb1 == "a2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb1 == "a3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb1 == "a4") {
$score--;

}



if($rb2 == "b1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb2 == "b2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb2 == "b3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb2 == "b4") {
$score--;

}


if($rb3 == "c1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb3 == "c2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb3 == "c3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb3 == "c4") {
$score--;

}



if($rb4 == "d1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb4 == "d2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb4 == "d3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb4 == "d4") {
$score--;

}


if($rb5 == "e1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb5 == "e2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb5 == "e3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb5 == "e4") {
$score--;

}



if($rb6 == "f1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb6 == "f2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb6 == "f3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb6 == "f4") {
$score--;

}


if($rb7 == "g1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb7 == "g2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb7 == "g3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb7 == "g4") {
$score--;

}


if($rb8 == "h1") {

$score++;

} else if($rb8 == "h2") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb == "h3") {
$score--;

}
else if($rb8 == "h4") {
$score--;

}

$query = "INSERT INTO wertetest VALUES ('$name', '$email',
'$stadt', '$land',   '$rb1', '$rb2', '$rb3', '$rb4',
'$rb5', '$rb6', '$rb7',  '$rb8', '$score')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
header ("refresh:50;url=http://link.com");
}

?>
```

page for db:
dbconfig.php

```
<?php

//Define your host here.
$hostname = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$username = "root";

//Define your database password here.
$password = "+++++++";

//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "dbtest1";

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

if (!$conn)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
?>
```

Comment: so somewhere here presumably lurks a question?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: yes thank you, I have forgotten